# Properly using Array of Structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm working on a program which uses threads to act as guests trying to check-in, utilize, and check-out of a Hotel.

In order to keep track of guest data across all threads, I'm using a `struct`:

```
struct thread_data
{
    int guest_id;   // id number of guest
    int room;       // room guest utilizes
    int event;      // 0=swim, 1=resturaunt, 2=fitness, 3=business
    int cost;       // final cost of stay (random value)
}
```

Since there will be multiple guests which use the Hotel, I try to create an array of guest structs:

```
struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS]; // array initialization
```

**Question 1:** Does this correctly create an array of type `struct`? Is the name of the array `thread_data_array`?

---

Further on, I have my `Guest()` method in which I try to get and set data from that `struct`:

```
void *Guest(void *guestData)
{
    int guestid, guestroom, gevent, gcost;
    struct thread_data *guest_data;

    guestroom = guest_data->room;

    gevent = getRandomLessThan(4);  // activity connected to 0, 1, 2, 3
    guest_data[guestid].event = gevent; // assign to Guest's struct
}
```

**Question 2:** Am I correctly "getting" and "setting" from my struct?

---

In short, I'm a bit consfused as to the correct naming for my three parts:

Struct: `struct thread_data;`

Array: `struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS];`

In Main(): `struct thread_data *guest_data;`

---

Here's my whole program, all errors included:

```
//Hotel Project 
//This project creates a system to simulate a hotel.

#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NUM_GUESTS  10 //10 guests

void *CheckIn(void *); // the two threads
void *CheckOut(void *);

pthread_t guests[NUM_GUESTS];

sem_t roomSem;              //total number of rooms in the hotel
sem_t check_in, check_out;  //reception desks
sem_t s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;   //global semaphores

int rooms[5];   //keep track of availability of each room

int total_guests;       //incremented with each guest check-out
int pool;               //incremented with each guest use pool
int resturant;          //incremented with each guest use resturant
int fitness_center;     //incremented with each guest use fitness center
int business_center;    //incremented with each guest use business center

struct thread_data
{
    int guest_id;   // id number of guest
    int room;       // room guest utilizes
    int event;      // 0=swim, 1=resturaunt, 2=fitness, 3=business
    int cost;       // final cost of stay (random value)
}

struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS]; // array initialization


void *Guest(void *guestData)
{
int guestNumber = *(int *) guestData; //error?
int guestid, guestroom, gevent, gcost;
struct thread_data *guest_data;

guestid = (struct int) guestData; //error?

//guest_data = (struct thread_data *) guestData;
//guestid = guest_data->guest_id; // guestID stored in the struct

/*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for room to be available\n", guestid);
sem_wait(&roomSem); // guest wants a room; check to see if one is available

/*output*/ printf("Guest %d waits for check-in\n", guestid);
sem_wait(&check_in); // if there is a room available, guest approaches check_in clerk; making him busy
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d goes to the check-in reservationist\n", guestid);
CheckIn(thread_data_array[guestid]); //check in
sem_post(&s1); // event ordering

sem_wait(&s2);
guestroom = guest_data->room;
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d receives Room %d and completes check-in\n", guestid, room);

sem_post(&check_in); // event ordering. Check-In now available

gevent = getRandomLessThan(4);  // activity connected to 0, 1, 2, 3
guest_data[guestid].event = gevent; // assign to Guest's struct

switch(gevent)
{
    case(0): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Pool\n", guestid);
            pool++;

    case(1): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Resturant\n", guestid);
            resturant++;

    case(2): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Fitness Center\n", guestid);
            fitness_center++;

    case(3): /*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: Business Center\n", guestid);
            business_center++;
}
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d does event: %d\n", guestid, gevent);

sleep(getRandomLessThan(5) - 1); // sleep for 1 to 3 seconds

gcost = getRandomLessThan(300);     // 0 < cost < 300
guest_data[guestid].cost = gcost;   // maybe should be in CheckOut
//thread_data_array[guest].cost = money;

sem_wait(&check_out); // guest waits for check-out desk to be available
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d goes to the check-out reservationist and returns room %d\n", guestid, room);
sem_post(&s3); // event ordering

printf("Main: Creating CheckOut thread %d", guestid);
rc = pthread_create(&guest[guestid], NULL, CheckOut, (void *)&thread_data_array[guest]);
if (rc){
    printf("ERROR1; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
    exit(-1);
}

sem_wait(&s4); // event ordering
total = thread_data_array[guestid].cost;
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d receives the total balance of $%d\n", guestid, total);
/*output*/ printf("Guest %d makes a payment\n", guestid);
total_guests++;
sem_post(&s5); // event ordering

}

int getRandomLessThan(int x)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % x;
    printf("Random number: %d\n", r);

    return r;
}

int GetOpenRoom()
{
    for (int i=0; i<rooms.length; i++)
    {
        if (rooms[i] = 1) // room vacant
        {
            rooms[i] = 0; // mark as filled
            return i;
        }
    }
}

void *CheckIn(void *guestData)
{
int guestid, guestroom;
struct thread_data *guest_data;
guest_data = (struct thread_data *) guestData;

guestid = guest_data->guest_id; // guestID stored in the struct
/**/guestroom = guest_data->room; // room stored in the struct
/**/printf("Guestroom: %d", guestroom); // expecting NULL

sem_wait(&s1); // event ordering

/*output*/ printf("The check-in reservationist greets Guest %d\n", guestid);
sem_wait(&roomSem); // use a room
guestroom = GetOpenRoom();
guest_data[guestid].room = guestroom; // mark room number in guest's struct
//thread_data_array[guestid].room = guestroom;
//which do i need?

/*output*/ printf("Assign room %d to Guest %d\n", guestroom, guestid);

sem_post(&s2); // event ordering

pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *CheckOut(void *guestData)
{
int guestid, guestroom, guestcost;
struct thread_data *guest_data;

guest_data = (struct thread_data *) guestData;
guestid = guest_data->guest_id; // guestID stored in the struct
guestroom = guest_data->room; // room stored in the struct
guestcost = guest_data->cost; // cost stored in the struct

sem_wait(&s3); // event ordering
/*output*/ printf("The check-out greets Guest %d and receives the key from room %d\n", guestid, guestroom);
rooms[guestroom] = 1; // room now available, set back to 1
sem_post(&roomSem); // release a room
/*output*/ printf("Calculate the balance for Guest %d\n", guestid);
//case situation for each event. makes guestcost= different value for each event
thread_data_array[guestid].cost = guestcost;
sem_post(&s4); // event ordering
sem_wait(&s5); // event ordering
/*output*/ printf("Receive $%d from Guest %d and complete the check-out\n", cost, guestid);

pthread_exit(NULL);
}



//Guest
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t desk[2];
int rc;
int guest;
struct thread_data *guest_data;

sem_init(&roomSem, 1, 5); //not 0 means shared between multiple processes, 5 is initial value
sem_init(&check_in, 1, 1);
sem_init(&check_out, 1, 1);
sem_init(&s1, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s2, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s3, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s4, 1, 0);
sem_init(&s5, 1, 0);

rooms[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};

pthread_create(&desk[0], NULL, CheckIn, NULL);  // Check In runs on it's own now
pthread_create(&desk[1], NULL, CheckOut, NULL); // Check Out runs on it's own now

for(guest = 0; guest < NUM_GUESTS; guest++)
{
    int *guestNumber = malloc(sizeof(*guestNumber);
    guestNumber = guest;
    //thread_data_array[guest].guest_id = guest; // guest ID for each guest thread
    rc = pthread_create(guests[guest], NULL, Guest, guestNumber); //Guest method, guest argument
    //Guest only takes a void argument. Must use thread_data_array?
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create(Guest) is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

printf("\t\t\tNumber of Customers\n");
printf("Total Guests:\t%d\n", total_guests);
printf("Pool:\t%d\n", pool);
printf("Resturant:\t%d\n", resturant);
printf("Fitness Center:\t%d\n", fitness_center);
printf("Business Center:\t%d\n", business_center);

sem_close(&roomSem);
sem_close(&check_in);
sem_close(&check_out);
sem_close(&s1);
sem_close(&s2);
sem_close(&s3);
sem_close(&s4);
sem_close(&s5);

pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**EDIT: I am using void pointers as arguments in my threads because I am using pthread_create()**

Comment: Declaring, allocating, and initializing are three different things.

Comment: `guestid = (struct int) guestData;` makes absolutely no sense. `int` is not the name of a structure.

Comment: Note that your definition of `struct thread_data` is missing a `;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

Yes, `struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS];` is creating `thread_data_array` as array with `NUM_GUESTS` elements of type `struct thread_data`.

**Question 2:**

`guest_data` is a pointer to your struct, but is not initialized (points nowhere):

```
struct thread_data *guest_data;

guestroom = guest_data->room;
```

Comment: How is your code for question 2 different from the code in the question?

Comment: @Barmar: It's not different. It's just the erroneous part copied to show it.

Comment: A useful answer should show how to fix erroneous code, not just parrot it back.

Comment: Can you show me how I should correct this?  
I'm not sure what it means to say that it "points nowhere" when I feel like it's holding all the data, and points (`->`) to specify what piece of data to get.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

Yes, you **define** an array of `struct thread_data` named `thread_data_array`. However, your comment is not correct. The array is left **uninitialized**, in other words, is a chunk of memory whose value is random.
**Definition** and **Initialization** are two things in C. You could combine the two things in one statement. For example,

```
int a = 0;  // for primitive type
struct thread_data thread_data_array[2] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1}
}; // define and initialize an array of size 2 of your struct type
```

### Question 2: Issue of your second piece of code

`struct thread_data *guest_data` is uninitialized, which means `guest_data` is a random pointer, or seriously, dangerous pointer. I guess you intended to set `guest_data` pointer to input value

```
guest_data = (struct thread_data *)guestData;
```

As `struct` is a chunk of memory, fields defined inside `struct` will be converted to an offset to the very beginning of memory address of this struct object by compiler in compile-time. `void *` pointer to any memory address, you can not use it as an representation of an array since dereference `void *` will get `void` which has no member field.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are creating ok, and correct name.
2. No. `guest_data` is not initialized.

There is no reason to use `void *` in the call.  You should use the proper type. To pass a pointer to your array, change the signature to:

```
void *Guest(struct thread_data * thread_data_array)
```

If you don't give it the right type, then you won't be able to index into the array.

```
thread_data_array[guestid].event = gevent;
```

naming of parts:

Struct: struct thread_data;  // type name (not a variable)

Array: struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_GUESTS]; // array name

struct thread_data *guest_data; // pointer to a struct, which could be part of the array

Comment: I use `void *` because I create the Guest using `pthread_create()` which I believe requires a void pointer

Comment: The argument to `pthread_create` needs to be a pointer to an existing object.  You can pass any pointer to a function taking `void *`.